# how to get data in double quotes after splitJson Processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I get data in double quotes after using splitJson processor.

I am using SplitJson for splitting this array, but the data I am getting in Flowfiles is without double quotes while I need data to be in double quotes.

This is the array

```
["Consultation" ,"X","Y", "Z"]
```

This is SplitJSON processor Configuration
[image]

This is the Flowfile Data, I want this in double quotes as "Consultation". Ho wcan I get so?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ReplaceText` processor:

- `Search Value`: `(?s)(^.*$)`
- `Replacement Value`: `"$1"`

**Input**:

```
Consultation
```

**Output**:

```
"Consultation"
```